# Maneira correta de bindar um DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Estou *bindando* um `DataGridView` em um `DataTable` que retorno do meu Bd, mas mesmo com apenas **79 registros** no `DataTable` o meu `DataGridView` fica bem lento para trabalhar e travando na rolagem da tela.

Tem algum jeito melhor de eu realizar esse *bind* de modo que fique mais performático?

Há maneira mais recomendada?

```js
DataTable dtDados = DataAccess.ExecutaComando("SELECT ID, TOPICO_PTBR, TOPICO_ENUS, TOPICO_ESES, CONTEXTO_PTBR, CONTEXTO_ENUS, CONTEXTO_ESES, TEXTO_PTBR, TEXTO_ENUS, TEXTO_ESES, DATALT, REVISADO_ENUS, REVISADO_ESES FROM HELP ORDER BY TOPICO_PTBR");
dataGridView1.DataSource = dtDados;
```

**Número de registros retornados pela consulta: 79.**

Comment: inclua o markup do seu gridview na pergunta

Comment: O que seria o Markup? @LeandroAngelo

Comment: o código do aspx

Comment: É em Windows Forms...

Answer (score 0):

Lento com apenas essa quantidade de registros? Bem estranho mesmo... Geralmente preencho uma lista genérica e passo via um loop, acredito que seja mais rápido.

DataTable usa muita memória do computador, muitos até indicam não usar ele diretamente. Quando utilizo data table, geralmente é na camada de dados mas sempre usando um limitador de registros como **MaxReg** e **StartReg** do DataAdpter. Mas isso é no caso de você ter muitos registros, onde precise fazer uma paginação por exemplo.

Mas mesmo assim... não é normal acontecer isso já resolveu?